# How would you simplify this process?

Tags: html, excel, ms-word, workflow, jpeg

I have a bunch (over 1000) HTML files with just simple text. It's just a combination of text within a `<table>`. It's an internal batch of documents, not for web production.

The job we have is to convert them into JPEG files using Photoshop and the old copy paste method. It's tedious.

Is there a way you would do this process to make it more efficient/easier/simple?

I thought about trying to convert the HTML into Excel and then mail merging it into Word to print as JGEG. But I can't find (and rightly so) anything to convert HTML to XLSX.

Thoughts? Or is this just a manual job?

Comment: This might help you (it's old, but there are some places to start): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183107/automated-screenshots.  Also browserstack has a screen capture feature you can automate: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots

Comment: @BarbaraLaird I thought about that, but from the HTML I need to alter the styling. Just font face and sizing.

Comment: Can you make a single HTML document out of them, then open it in Word?  You haven't explained why Excel/xlsx has any role to play?

Comment: @JasonPlutext If you've ever used the Mail Merge feature in Word, then using a table from Excel is best practice. If you haven't, then it's like being able to use the rows of data as fields in Word to populate the data. Like when you add page numbers at the bottom of your Word documents. Effectively, using Excel would simplify this process unless theres a direct HTML to JPEG with styling options existing.

Comment: Sure.  So you mean your HTML contains raw data that you want to use as a mail merge source for Word?  That's not obvious from your question as currently stated. Maybe the JPEG part should be a separate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was looking for answer that works, I ended up using a program called Prince: https://www.princexml.com

It works amazingly, and just have to target the HTML with CSS or JS to make it match your output!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little something I created to convert a single html file to jpeg. It's not pretty (to say the least), but it works fine with a table larger than my screen. Put it inside a windows forms project. You can add more checks and call this program in a loop, or refactor it to work on multiple html files.

Ideas and techniques taken from -

Finding the needed size - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f6f0c641-43bd-44cc-8be0-12b40fbc4c43/webbrowser-object-use-to-find-the-width-of-a-web-page

Creating the graphics - http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/a/How-To-Save-Web-Page-Screen-Grab-csharp.htm

A table for example - copy-paste enlarged version of http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

```
static class Program
{

    static WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    private static string m_fileName;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (args.Length != 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usage: [fileName]");
            return;
        }

        m_fileName = args[0];
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (a, b) => webBrowser_DocumentCompleted();
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false; // Don't want them rendered
        webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(m_fileName));


        Application.Run();
    }

    static void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted()
    {

        // Get the needed size of the control
        webBrowser.Width = webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width + webBrowser.Margin.Horizontal;
        webBrowser.Height = webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height + webBrowser.Margin.Vertical;

        // Create the graphics and save the image
        using (var graphics = webBrowser.CreateGraphics())
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(webBrowser.Size.Width, webBrowser.Size.Height, graphics);
            webBrowser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, webBrowser.ClientRectangle);

            string newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(m_fileName, ".jpg");

            bitmap.Save(newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        // Shamefully exit the application
        Application.ExitThread();            
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know anything about c+ or even how to implement this.. but I'm going to assume this works

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv - this is C#. You'll have to compile it with Visual Studio and run it on a machine with .net installed. Don't assume anything, compile it and give it a try. You can use the express version of Visual Studio which is free to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all files in one page and use this lib [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) to covert.

You can running in the background use nodejs with [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas) or make it a desk app with [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)