# Dynamic iframe linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a list of HTML files with only a `<table>` inside them. The names of the files are all different (obviously).

I want to write a page up to link to those initial HTML files by including them as and `<iframe>`.

My question is:

**Is there any way to have one main webpage (that contains the iframe) to open all the individual files (with the tables) in new tabs?**

---

I know that's a big confusing of a question but here's my idea:

- have a main page that loads the table via iframe
- style that iframe externally with JS to match my CSS likings/needs
- screenshot the iframe (which would be my intended dimensions) > hopefully automatically

Figure out if that's the best way to answer my own StackOverflow question: [How would you simplify this process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18244437/1086990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. However you could create a main.php file and accomplish the task using PHP. This would require the file be hosted on a PHP server.

To host the files on your own computer for testing see this link to the [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) site or purchase space from a host.

iFrames can be used like the following.

```
<iframe>
    <p>This is my iframe</p>
</iframe>
```

Therefore you can use a PHP includes statement to embed your tables from external files. The following is an example two files and how the PHP server will display the file to the web browser.

**main.php**

```
<iframe>
    <?php include 'fileWithTableElements.html'; ?>
</iframe>
```

**findTableWithElements.html**

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>This is a test included Table</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**How the browser reads the HTML**

```
<iframe>
    <table>
       <tr>
           <td>This is a test included Table</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</iframe>
```

Because we are using the [PHP includes](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) function the PHP Server places your html files only containing tables between the iframe tags in your main.php document. This is one of many way you could quickly include HTML before the browser reads the document. PHP is one of the easiest and fastest options.